# Telegram bot not sending old messages as scheduled

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

good afternoon!
I'm having a problem with this code, it doesn't resend messages as it should resend, I run it and nothing happens, it doesn't give any error message. not even chatgpt is knowing how to help me. Does anyone know what to do?
bot functions: Literally takes the last 10 messages from a user and channel on telegram and sends it to you and to two different channels.
I just run it and nothing happens

I tried this code and some variants of it

from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater

```
TOKEN = ''
CHANNEL_ID = ''
GROUP_IDS = ['']
USER_ID = ''  # ID do usuário específic`your text`o

def reencaminhar_mensagens_antigas(bot: Bot):
    channel = bot.get_chat(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID)
    members = bot.get_chat_member(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, user_id=USER_ID)

    if members.can_send_messages:
        messages = bot.get_chat_member_messages(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, user_id=USER_ID, limit=10)
        for message in messages:
            if message.photo or (message.video and message.caption):
                legenda = message.caption

                # Reencaminhar a foto ou vídeo com legenda para o canal 1
                if message.photo:
                    photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
                    bot.send_photo(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, photo=photo, caption=legenda)
                elif message.video:
                    video = message.video.file_id
                    bot.send_video(chat_id=CHANNEL_ID, video=video, caption=legenda)

                # Reencaminhar a foto ou vídeo com legenda para os canais 2
                for group_id in GROUP_IDS:
                    if message.photo:
                        photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
                        bot.send_photo(chat_id=group_id, photo=photo, caption=legenda)
                    elif message.video:
                        video = message.video.file_id
                        bot.send_video(chat_id=group_id, video=video, caption=legenda)

def start_bot():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
    reencaminhar_mensagens_antigas(bot=bot)

    # Inicie o bot
    updater = Updater(bot=bot, use_context=True)
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()

start_bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of the class `ChatMember` which is returned by `bot.get_chat_member_messages`, the class has many features deprecated recently and it doesn't currently contain `can_send_messages` among the methods.
https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.chatmember.html

Based on that, I can assume, that you bot can't pass the condition
`if members.can_send_messages:`

However, I would recommend testing that. It helps to add logging or printing to your code to see where the bot is getting stuck. This is especially important when you have so many conditions for something to happen, as your bot does.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method called `Bot.get_chat_member_messages` and there never was - for the simple reason that the [Telegram Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api) does not provide such a method.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.